# Criar uma validação no JavaScript, onde o formulário será válido caso o número B seja maior que o número A

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Fala galera não estou conseguindo desenvolver um formulário HTML que possua dois campos numéricos, campo A e campo B e um botão para, submeter o formulário, criei uma validação no JavaScript, onde o formulário será válido caso o número B seja maior que o número A, mas não ta funcionando, alguém pode me dar um explicação, sou inciante, estudante em transição de carreira.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form-confirm');
let ValA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-a').value);
let ValB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-b').value);

formValid = false;

function numbervalid (ValB, ValA    ){
    return ValB > ValB;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //previne carregamento da página após "submit"
    const messagesucess = 'formulario enviado com sucesso! Verificando: <b> ValorA menor que ValorB!</B>';
    formValid = numbervalid();
    if (formValid){
        const containermessagesucess = document.querySelector('.success-message');
        containermessagesucess.innerHTML = messagesucess;
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'nenhum';

        ValA.value = ' ';
        ValB.value = ' ';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'block';
    }    
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
  
}

body {
    display: block;    
}

.container {
    margin: 80px auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    width: 100%;
}

form {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

input, textarea, button {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
}

button {
    background-color: #0d09ed;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #6992f2;
}

.success-message {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

.error-message {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Integrando HTML com JavaScript</h1>
        <h2>Validação no JavaScript</h2>
        <form id="form-confirm">
            <label for="A"><b>Valor_A</b></label>
            <input type="number" id="valor-a" required placeholder="Digite o valor A" />
            <label for="B"><b>Valor_B</b></label>
            <input type="number" id="valor-b" required placeholder="Digite o valor B" />
            <p class="error-message">
                O valor B precisa ser maior que o valor A!
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Validar</button>
        </form>
        <p class="success-message"></p>
    </div>
</nav> 
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, as variáveis:

`let ValA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-a').value);`

`let ValB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-b').value);`

Devem estar dentro do:

`form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){ ... }`

Assim:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form-confirm');

let formValid = false;

function numbervalid (ValA, ValB){
    return ValB > ValA;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //previne carregamento da página após "submit"
    let ValA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-a').value);
    let ValB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-b').value);

    const messagesucess = 'formulario enviado com sucesso! Verificando: <b> ValorA menor que ValorB!</B>';
    const containermessagesucess = document.querySelector('.success-message');
    
    formValid = numbervalid(ValA, ValB);
    
    if (formValid){
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';
        containermessagesucess.innerHTML = messagesucess;
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';

        ValA.value = '';
        ValB.value = '';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'block';
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

> Isso porquê, quando clicar no botão, ele irá pegar o valor atual dos input para fazer as validações e etc... Se você deixar fora desse evento, nunca será atualizado os valores.

Segundamente, a função `numbervalid` está errada. Você está verificando se `B > B`, quando deveria ser `B > A`. Os parâmetros estão errados também. Corrigindo, fica assim:

```
function numbervalid (ValA, ValB){
    return ValB > ValA;
}
```

E por último, você esqueceu de passar os valores ao chamar a função: `formValid = numbervalid();`

Deve ser assim:

`formValid = numbervalid(ValA, ValB);`

Corrigindo todo o seu código, fica assim:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form-confirm');

let formValid = false;

function numbervalid (ValA, ValB){
    return ValB > ValA;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //previne carregamento da página após "submit"
    let ValA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-a').value);
    let ValB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-b').value);

    const messagesucess = 'formulario enviado com sucesso! Verificando: <b> ValorA menor que ValorB!</B>';
    const containermessagesucess = document.querySelector('.success-message');
    
    formValid = numbervalid(ValA, ValB);
    
    if (formValid){
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';
        containermessagesucess.innerHTML = messagesucess;
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';

        ValA.value = '';
        ValB.value = '';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'block';
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

Completo, com o trecho de js, html e css:

**OBS: É necessário validar isso no servidor, com `PHP` ou outra linguagem para servidor que você esteja usando, pois validar só no JS não protege 100%**

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form-confirm');

let formValid = false;

function numbervalid (ValA, ValB){
    return ValB > ValA;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //previne carregamento da página após "submit"
    let ValA = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-a').value);
    let ValB = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor-b').value);

    const messagesucess = 'formulario enviado com sucesso! Verificando: <b> ValorA menor que ValorB!</B>';
    const containermessagesucess = document.querySelector('.success-message');
    
    formValid = numbervalid(ValA, ValB);
    
    if (formValid){
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';
        containermessagesucess.innerHTML = messagesucess;
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'none';

        ValA.value = '';
        ValB.value = '';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('.error-message').style.display = 'block';
        containermessagesucess.style.display = 'none';
    }    
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
  
}

body {
    display: block;    
}

.container {
    margin: 80px auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    width: 100%;
}

form {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

input, textarea, button {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
}

button {
    background-color: #0d09ed;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #6992f2;
}

.success-message {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

.error-message {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Integrando HTML com JavaScript</h1>
        <h2>Validação no JavaScript</h2>
        <form id="form-confirm">
            <label for="A"><b>Valor_A</b></label>
            <input type="number" id="valor-a" required placeholder="Digite o valor A" />
            <label for="B"><b>Valor_B</b></label>
            <input type="number" id="valor-b" required placeholder="Digite o valor B" />
            <p class="error-message">
                O valor B precisa ser maior que o valor A!
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Validar</button>
        </form>
        <p class="success-message"></p>
    </div>
</nav> 
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Valeu Sr. Caveira vc é o cara, muito obrigado.

Comment: É nois, Julio! Boa sorte com seu projeto.